# Fine Uploader uuid unique?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I think about using Fine Uploader uuid values as a unique identifier in a database table (to associate files with uploads).

However, is it guaranteed, that Fine Uploader uuid's are always unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine Uploader generates a [version 4 UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).  This essentially means that Fine Uploader's client-side UUID is just a random number.  This is the best that we can do client-side.  It's always *possible* that a collision will occur, but I haven't run into an issue yet.  Note that we not only develop Fine Uploader at Widen, we also use it in all of our products.

If you are concerned about this, you may generate a version 1 or version 2 UUID server-side, and return it in the upload request response as [described in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html#providing-your-own-uuid-for-files).  Fine Uploader will then use your server-generated UUID to identify the file from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[this](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/733#issuecomment-14623953)** link, yes:

> *"The UUID is an ID, also created by Fine Uploader, unique among all sessions."*

Comment: It looks like Ray Nicholus wrote the sentence in the link you mention. So I think I gonna go with his answer. But thanks for digging this out.